# draw ellipse inside ellipse with timer c#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a program in winforms with tool strip menu with the buttons: +, -.
each time i click the + it draws a growing ellipse, and when i cick the - it disappear. 
now, i managed to draw the growing ellipse, but when i click the + again it draws new elipse. i need the new ellipse to start inside the previous ellipse i drew. 
so when i click 3 times for example, there will be 3 ellipse one inside the other.
and when i click the - the last ellipse i drew will disappear. i have constraint to use draImage().
my question is: how can i make a new ellipse inside the previous when i click the + again?
when i click the + it just erase the previous and start drawing new ellipse.
 my code looks like this:

Form.cs :

```
public partial class TheBalls : Form
    {
        private Ball yourBall;

        public TheBalls()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            yourBall = new Ball(this);
        }

        Graphics flagGraphics;
        List<Ball> list = new List<Ball> { };

        private void plusButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            yourBall = new Ball(this);
            list.Add(yourBall);
            yourBall.Growing();
        }

        private void minusButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                list[list.Count - 1].clr = Color.Transparent;
                list.RemoveAt(list.Count -1);
            }
        }

        private void TheBalls_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(yourBall.Center.X * 2, yourBall.Center.Y * 2);
            flagGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            yourBall.Update(flagGraphics);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }


    }
```

ball class: (the ellipse)

```
class Ball
    {
        private Control canvas;
        private Timer t = new Timer();
        private int dir = 1;

        public Point Center { get; set; }
        public Color clr;
        public int Radius { get; set; }

        public Control Canvas
        {
            get { return canvas; }
            set
            {
                canvas = value;
                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    //canvas.SizeChanged -= Canvas_SizeChanged;
                    //canvas.SizeChanged += Canvas_SizeChanged;
                    Center = new Point(canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, canvas.ClientSize.Height/ 2);
                }
            }
        }
        private static readonly Random rand = new Random();

        public Ball(Control canvas)
        {
            clr = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255));
            if (canvas != null)
            {
                this.canvas = canvas;
                canvas.SizeChanged -= Canvas_SizeChanged;
                canvas.SizeChanged += Canvas_SizeChanged;
                Center = new Point(canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, canvas.ClientSize.Height / 2);

            }

            t.Interval = 10;
            t.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }
        private void Canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Center = new Point(canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, canvas.ClientSize.Height / 2);
        }
        public void Growing()
        {
            dir = 1;
            t.Enabled = true;

        }

        public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (canvas == null)
            {
                //t.Stop();
                clr = Color.Transparent;
                return;
            }
            Radius += dir;

            if (Radius > Math.Min(canvas.ClientSize.Width, canvas.ClientSize.Height) / 2)
            {
                Radius = Math.Min(canvas.ClientSize.Width, canvas.ClientSize.Height) / 2;
                clr = Color.Transparent;
            }
            canvas.Invalidate();
        }

        public void Update(Graphics g)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(clr), new Rectangle(Center.X - Radius, Center.Y - Radius, Radius * 2, Radius * 2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how can i make it ellipse inside ellipse when i click the + ? every time i click the plus it draws new ellipse instead of new one inside the previous.

Comment: Very nice. I also do programs from time to time ... do you have any questions?

Comment: i'm sorry i wasn't clear.. i edited the question.

Comment: @SoMoS i edited my question. i believe it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Now its more clear, yes. Correct me if I'm wrong but looks like you are not using the `list` variable at all while Painting, that's why you only draw one ball each time.

Comment: I only use the list variable to know which ball to "erase" when i click the - button.

Comment: even if i will use the list, how can it show on the form that the first ball will still grow and the second one will start to draw inside the first ? that's what i don't understand how to do..

Answer (score 1):

Change your TheBalls_Paint event like this :

```
 private void TheBalls_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(yourBall.Center.X * 2, yourBall.Center.Y * 2);
     flagGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
     foreach (var ball in list)
     {
         ball.Update(flagGraphics);
     }
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
 }
```

Comment: it works!!!! thank you! i tried to put the foreach in some place else, didn't think of it. thank you so much! :)

Comment: one more quest. when i click the + button several times the balls grow more slowly. why is that ? is it something with my intervals ?

Comment: In Timer_Tick event when a Ball make big enough, you just change its colour to transparent.Just make Timer stop.

Comment: i did it now as you said. it is still going slower

Comment: is there a way to erase the ball from the form ? so it won't make it slow?

Comment: To make ball invisible readd your Transparent code after the Timer stop codeline.In Form code you add Balls to a list. But you dont erase balls from list when ball get big enough.That makes your program getting slower.

Comment: even when i remove balls from list it still slow. when i for example click + 3 times and then - 3 times, then the list empty, and when i click again on the + then it starts slow.